# Python thread lifetime and handling

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface

I have created a GUI for a python program which can launch 4 different independent computations. I want the GUI to be responsive while the computations happen at the background, so I create a new thread for each computation. I also keep some additional information about the thread (for example if it should abort the computation).

Each computation can also be run multiple times (either after being aborted or after changing some settings) which means multiple threads can be created for each computation.

I'm not sure if I have to explicitly join each thread using .join() or if the thread terminates and joins automatically after the function has finished execution. I don't want to end up with 100 threads at the end of my program if they don't automatically join the main thread after termination.

I know I can use thread.is_alive() to check if a thread has finished execution, but I really don't want to write some sort of a thread garbage collector (which has to run in its own new thread ... sigh) if I don't have to. I have done some googling but I can't find documentation about thread lifetime when not explicitly using .join().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main can exit and if they are daemon threads they'll be killed uncleanly.

Threads can exit at any time in which case joining will immediately return.

If they aren't daemon threads there's an implicit join - but unless you've asked them to terminate they'll continue until whatever they're doing has finished.

The docs say: **"the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left"**

And: **Note: Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event**

From: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

But if you're asking the threads to terminate cooperatively then you should join on them all because you want to be certain they finished cleanly. This does put the onus on you to design the threads so they terminate in a timely manned (i.e. not excessively delying the user) when requested - but that's how threads work, isn't it.

Comment: that basically does mean that I have to create an automatic thread handler then. The easiest way I can think of doing this is to only allow one active thread per function (with signals (easiest way would be a global variable that keeps track of the thread state, which is checked in a while loop instead of using for loops)). When the tkinter window is destroyed, all of the signals tell the calculations to terminate and applies join on all of them. Does that seem like a viable approach or are there better ways of handling this?

Comment: A (possibly global) variabl;e to keep a list of the threads, and a uniform mechanism for requesting them to stop, seems sensible.